# jQuery Make a Link in Active Status

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a HTML template, but I cannot touch the HTML code, I can only work on CSS and JS files. So I cannot in any way edit the HTML code.

What I am trying to achieve is to put some links in active status when jQuery or Javascript recognizes that the current page URL is the same one of the link I want to put in active status, without editing the HTML code.

Is there a way to do it? I tried in many ways but with no luck.

Here is the HTML code ( Remember I cannot edit it ).

```
<span class="Tag_Nav_Aux">
    <a href="/my-account/create-account.aspx">Create&nbsp;Account</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="/my-account/login.aspx">Login</a>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a href="/my-cart/default.aspx">My Cart</a>
</span>
```

The jQuery or Javascript code should work on different links, other than the ones I reported above, since the HTML changes when the user is logged in or logged out.
So the jQuery should point the class `Tag_Nav_Aux` and add the Active class to any `a` tag it will find that has the link the same of the current URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.Tag_Nav_Aux a').filter(function(){
       return $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() === window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();
    }).addClass('active');
});
```

and create a CSS rule for

```
.Tag_Nav_Aux a.active{
   // style you want the active link to have
}
```

Comment: Look good. Will this work if we pass a query string value like /product/item.aspx?id=8

Comment: nope. `pathname` is "*This attribute represents the path component of the Location's URI which consists of everything **after the host and port up to and excluding the first question mark (?) or hash mark (#).***" See http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this. Your file name from the URL

```
var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

After that get the anchor from the navigation and apply some class.

```
$("span.Tag_Nav_Aux a[href*="+filename+"]").addClass('active');
```

Here you have to write a CSS `active` class which will make that link to appear like an active link.

Comment: if we have Url like http://localhost:50126/my-account/create-account.aspx/ , your code will work? what will be the filename ?

Comment: `create-account.aspx` If you see the code properly it is taking the index of last `\` and its content after that.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href.toLowerCase();

    $(".Tag_Nav_Aux a").each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);

        var href = $this.attr("href").toLowerCase();

        if(url.indexOf(href) > -1) {
            $this.addClass("active");            
        }           
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the current page url and assign a class to the item like to active.

I usually do putting class="active" based on current URL match with help of server side code.

But if you dont want server code you can do with help of JavaScript

```
var currentPage=window.location.href;

if(currentPage=="") 
{ 
 //logic to find and add a Class for the proper anchor tag
 }
```