# How to set active state for checkbox using JS/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a couple of functions that sort property listings with php. The sorting works, however I need to set active states for the current active clicked href. Of course I couldn't be so lucky as to set this with CSS only (although I've included my CSS snippet below for reference) so I am attempting to do so with jQuery but have been unsuccessful so far.. You can find my php, jquery, and css below. If anyone can guide me in the right direction I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

```
<div>   
    <?php
        foreach( array('desc'=>$main_floor_master) as $asc_desc => $asc_desc_name ) {
        echo '<a class="filter-checkboxes" href="'; 
        echo add_query_arg( array( 'orderby' => main_floor_master, 'order' => $asc_desc)
        );
        echo "\">Main Floor Master</a>";
        }
    ?>  

    <?php
        foreach( array('desc'=>$locality_status) as $asc_desc => $asc_desc_name ) {
        echo '<a class="filter-checkboxes"  href="'; 
        echo add_query_arg( array( 'orderby' => status, 'order' => $asc_desc)
        );
        echo "\">Quick Move In</a>";
        }
    ?>
</div>


<!-- Active states -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //active state  
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.parent().addClass('active');

        });
    });
});
</script>


<!-- CSS -->
a.filter-checkboxes {color: #cacaca !important; font-weight: bold; background: url(images/btn-checkboxbg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; padding-left: 24px; margin-left: 10px;}
a.filter-checkboxes:active {color: #cacaca; font-weight: bold; background: url(images/btn-checkboxbg_selected.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; padding-left: 24px; margin-left: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Try the code above. You don't have to cache an object unless you are using it multiple times in your code snippet.

and create a CSS rule for

```
a.active{ // 
   // style you want the active link to have
}
```

Note that it should `a.filter-checkboxes.active` Not `a.filter-checkboxes:active`

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039968/jquery-make-a-link-in-active-status)

Comment: And change `a.filter-checkboxes:active` to `a.filter-checkboxes.active`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.filter-checkboxes').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('.active').toggleClass('active');
         $(this).toggleClass('active');

    });
```

This will remove the previous active class (Assuming you can't have two sorts active at once), and set the class on the newly clicked element. Plus I've changed the selector to make it more specific so it doesn't run on every `<a>` tag on the page.

Also change the css to:

```
a.filter-checkboxes {color: #cacaca !important; font-weight: bold; background: url(images/btn-checkboxbg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; padding-left: 24px; margin-left: 10px;}    
a.filter-checkboxes.active {color: #cacaca; font-weight: bold; background: url(images/btn-checkboxbg_selected.jpg) no-repeat 0 0; padding-left: 24px; margin-left: 10px;}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have change my css accordingly (not sure why I had :active vs .active) and tried both options to still no success unfortunately. Do is still need "$(document).ready(function(){"? Heres how I have my code:    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //active state  
         $('.filter-checkboxes').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('.active').toggleClass('active');
         $(this).toggleClass('active');

    });
    </script>

Comment: OK, I have been able to successfully apply the active state with suggestion (I had to change the $ to jQuery) but the sort stopped working (the page doesnt change or do anything). Is there something else that needs to be added? Thanks again for all the help so far!

Comment: Hey all, thanks again for the replies. Again, I was able to get the active state to work onclick but the page does not change. Do I need to add something like a var url change function in addition the the active function or am I just doing something wrong? Really appreciate all and any insight. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry been away for a few days. Your using Wordpress correct? What happens if you remove the jQuery on click event, does the sort then work?