# Set active link with jQuery in multipage page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know its not the first question.

I tried from [jQuery Make a Link in Active Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039968/jquery-make-a-link-in-active-status), but its not working, when I click to go different page the `'a'` didnt have class active. any suggestion thanks.

```
<nav class="main-navi">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html">
        Home
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="corner"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="portfolio.html">
        Portfolio
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="corner"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="about.html">
        About
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="corner"></span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="" href="service.html">
        services
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="corner"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="blog.html">
        Blog
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="corner"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="contact.html">
        contacts
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="corner"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <em id="showHideMenu" class="show-hide-menu fa fa-bars" href="#"></em>
</nav>
<script>
  jQuery(function($){
    $('.main-navi a').filter(function(){
      return $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase() === window.location.pathname.toLowerCase();
    }).addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: sorry, i have 6 pages. example:im in index page. and i click about.html and then it go to about page. in about page i want <a href="about.html">about</a> have class active

Comment: You want to add active class when you come bale to this original page?

Comment: The best way to go about this is to console.log(window.location.pathname) and see why it is not matching the href. It probably just have an extra slash or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var loc = window.location.pathname;

   $('.main-navi ul li').find('a').each(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('active', $(this).attr('href') == loc);
  });
```

and use full absolute path in href i.e.`http://yourdomain.com/index.html`

Comment: sorry, can you explain about http://yourdomain.com/index.html. cause it still a project not online web

Comment: That's very simple give the full path in `href` whatever it shows in your browsers address bar. so that it can match with `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: Thank you sir it workkk. Can i ask u something. In portfolio i have a button that if i click will go to detil portfolio page. How to make portfolio get class active on navbar when i load detil portfolio page?